# AWS: nodejs app can't connect to pg databse

Tags: node.js, postgresql, amazon-web-services

I am trying to upload a node app online on aws.
When I launch the app on local it works perfectly fine because my app finds access to postgres.
However when I upload my server, it then can't connect to the database. 
My app uses loopback.io.
Here is the server/config.json :

```
{
"restApiRoot": "/api",
"host": "0.0.0.0",
"port": 3000,
"remoting": {
  "context": false,
  "rest": {
     "handleErrors": false,
  "normalizeHttpPath": false,
  "xml": false
},
"json": {
  "strict": false,
  "limit": "100kb"
},
"urlencoded": {
  "extended": true,
  "limit": "100kb"
},
"cors": false
},
"legacyExplorer": false,
"logoutSessionsOnSensitiveChanges": true
}
```

And here is /server/datasources.json

```
{
"db": {
"name": "db",
"connector": "memory"
},
"postgres": {
"host": "localhost",
"port": 5432,
"url": "",
"database": "postgres",
"password": "postgresseason",
"name": "postgres",
"user": "postgres",
"connector": "postgresql"
}
}
```

I have done researches and I think I have to change an url so it doesn't try to look for a "local" way, but don't manage to make it work.
I tried using the url `postgress://postgres:postgresseason@db:5432/postgres` without success.

The error I am getting are either :

```
Web server listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8080
Browse your REST API at http://0.0.0.0:8080/explorer
Connection fails: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND db db:5432
It will be retried for the next request.
```

Or :

```
Web server listening at: http://0.0.0.0:3000
Browse your REST API at http://0.0.0.0:3000/explorer
Connection fails: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432
It will be retried for the next request.
```

Any help how to make it work?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the postgres server is installed and reachable by aws.

By default it cannot reach your locally installed postgres (without complicate port forwarding etc... )

If you are using ec2 you can install a postgres server locally and use localhost.
Or setting postgres in another aws service like this one: https://aws.amazon.com/rds/postgresql/
Just make sure the nodejs server / service has the required permissions to reach and query the postgres.